# Translate a shape into 2d space

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I'm completing a lab for college and I'm a little stuck on what it is the lecturer wants me to do, we've just started learning C#, the lab wants us to write a console application, using Polymorphism, has 4 classes: Vertex, Shape, Line, Circle and a test.

I have all my classes and most of my methods implemented fine, but I can't figure out what it is he wants us to do in the Translate method, below is the question as it appears on the lab sheet:

> Implement 2 methods in Shape, one to return details of the Shape
>   (ToString() ) and one to allow a shape to be translated in 2D space
>   (Translate(..)). The amount to be translated should be passed as a
>   parameter to the translate method (as a reference to a Vertex object
>   i.e. the amount the object is to be translated with respect to the X
>   and Y axes).

I'm pretty sure he's not looking for anything as complicated as the solution given here: [How to Draw Box,Rectangle in a C# Console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858904/how-to-draw-box-rectangle-in-a-c-sharp-console-application)

Any suggestions appreciated.

Edit

this is my code so far:

```
 public override void Translate(ref Vertex v)
    {


    }
```

The method is implemented as a virtual method in the Shape class and is overridden in the Line and Circle class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Translation in this context means "shift" (and you will see this concept come up in GUI frameworks, such as `TranslateTransform`)

For example a `Circle` centered on the origin translated 2 units up, and to the right would become a circle centered at (2,2).

Since translation requires 2 pieces of information (how much to go left-right and up-down), you can reuse the `Vertex` object (which presumably has those two pieces of information stored as `X` and `Y` properties) to pass the translation parameters like so:

```
public virtual void Translate(Vertex translation)
{
    //Implementation left to you
}
```

Each class would override this method to do its own translation. Note that there is no need to actually pass **by** reference here (as your code has), the object is *always* passed **as** a reference.

Comment: Yes the Vertex class has an x and y field and I know I have to use them in the implementation of the Translate method, but it's the implementation where I'm struggling, Am I printing values? or trying to draw the shape?
Sorry if I'm missing something small here.

Comment: @Johntk If I had to guess, you are supposed to just modify internal properties that will be printed when `ToString` is called. Thats all I can assume without seeing the whole assignment though. Really, a question you can and should ask your instructor.

Comment: I will ask him, but wont see him till Monday, I have the thirst to learn now :)
Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Johntk No problem. Did you understand my comment about not passing by reference here?

Comment: Yes, I should have known that, I'm a bit rusty from the summer break and doing c++ last year, an object is always created as reference, or a pointer to the object on the heap, rather than pass by value, such as an int which is on the stack?

Comment: @Johntk Right, and the lines between stack and heap are a bit blurry (and not really important) in C#. Passing reference types in C# is analagous to passing by pointer in C++.